# Why @Table annotation is optional in CRUD operation through spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to spring and spring-boot and while learning Spring CRUD I was going through different articles and I saw these lines.

> "And why @Entity annotation is mandatory? … well, it is the way how JPA is designed. When you create a new entity you have to do at least two things
>   annotated it with @Entity
>   create an id field and annotate it with @Id
>   Anything else is optional, for example, the table name is derived from entity class name (and therefore @Table annotation can be optional), table’s columns are derived from entities variables (and therefore @Column annotation can be optional), and so on …"

So my question is how spring will bifurcate the tables and their column names if we do not provide `@Table` annotation and `@Column` annotations.

Comment: As mention in the statement they get it from your class name. If your class name is Users they consider your table name as users according to camel case notation.

Comment: As it says in your quote: *"[...] the table name is derived from entity class name [...], table’s columns are derived from entities variables [...]"*

Comment: The JPA specification defines precise rules about the name derivation algorithms. Spring has nothing to do with this: everything is done by the JPA implementation. Spring Boot, on the other hand, by default configures Hibernate with its own naming strategy, which it prefers to the standard one.

Comment: okay so, in that case, my entity class name should exactly similar to the table name. Got it Thank you for the response. : LIKE

Comment: No. Not at all. The entity class name should be the best name you can imagine for your entity, and respect the Java naming conventions for classes. If the derivation algorithm for that good class name doesn't produce the table name you want, then you just need to use the `@Table` annotation to specify a specific table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked your question in the context of Spring Boot. There are two options that determine the naming strategy:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy

This option is used to determine the names when we don't provide the table and column names explicitly in the entity definition

Usually this defaults to: `ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl`

More [implementations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy.html).

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy

This is more customizable, pluggable strategy contract for applying physical naming rules for database object names.

By default, a `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` is used where all dots camel casing is replaced by underscores. Also, table names are generated in the lower case.